# Getting Context of "this" inside a class and assigning to a class pointer TheClass*

Tags: c++, class, pthreads

```
class classe (){
public: 
    int key;

    static void *funct(void *context){
        printf("Output: %d, ", key);
    }

    void Go(){
        classe c = static_cast<this>(context); //<- This doesn't work, Context of this-> goes here
        pthread_create(&t, NULL, &classe::funct, c);
    }
};

int main(){

    classe c;
    c.key = 15;
    c.Go();

    c.key = 18;
    c.Go();
}
```

The output should be `Output: 15, Output: 18,`, the thing is to get context of `this` throws error.

Someone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see a few problems with your code:

First, `static_cast<>` requires a type in the `<>`, and `this` acts like a variable (so not a type).  The type of `this` is `classe*` (pointer to `classe` object) within `classe`.

Second, there is no `context` available in `classe:Go()`.  There is a parameter for `classe::fuct()` by that name, but that is not available where you want to use it.

Third, `pthread_create()` assumes a free function (or a static member function) and you provide a class member function (`classe::funct`).  Class memeber functions require an object to work on (sort of like an implicit parameter == `this`).  You also don't have a `t` defined in `classe::Go()` that you could pass to `pthread_create()`

You could try:

```
static void *funct(void *key){ // funct is now a free function, all data is provided to it
    printf("Output: %d, ", *static_cast<int*>(key)); 
} 

class classe ()
{ 
public:  
  int key; 

  void Go(){
    pthread t; 
    pthread_create(&t, NULL, funct, &key); // pass (address of) key to funct
  } 
}; 

int main(){ 

  classe c; 
  c.key = 15; 
  c.Go(); 

  c.key = 18; 
  c.Go(); 
}
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be a free function, a static member will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to define `context` somewhere. Second, `this` is a keyword that represents a pointer to the object that the member function is being called on. `static_cast` requires a type in the template argument. Replace `static_cast<this>` with `static_cast<classe*>`, and change the type of `c` to `classe *` in order for the statement to compile.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

class classe
{
public: 
    int key;

    static void* funct(void *context)
    {
        classe* c = static_cast<classe*>(context);
        printf("Output: %d, ", c->key);
        return context;
    }

    void Go()
    {
        pthread_t t;
        pthread_create(&t, NULL, &classe::funct, this);
        void* p = 0;
        pthread_join(t, &p);
    }
};

int main()
{
    classe c;
    c.key = 15;
    c.Go();

    c.key = 18;
    c.Go();
    return 0;
}
```

I moved using the context to the proper function, and added the pthread_join so the program won't exit before the threads have a chance to run.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be a little confused about where some of the key parts go. Here's a rough skeleton that I think does most of what you want.

```
class classe {
    public:
        classe(int k) : key(k) { }

        void Go() {
            // where does "t" come from?
            pthread_create(&t, NULL, &funct, static_cast<void*>(this));
        }

    private:
        int key;

        static void* funct(void* context) {
            classe* self = static_cast<classe*>(context);
            printf("Output: %d ", self->key);
            return 0; // not sure this is what you want
        }
};

int main() {
    classe c(15);
    c.Go();
}
```